# UTF-8 encoding error using Pandoc filters

Tags: pandoc

I have been having trouble when converting a Markdown file to PDF using pandoc-eqnos filter. I typed in command line:

```
pandoc --filter=pandoc-eqnos file.md -o file.pdf
```

And get the following error message:

`File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\pandoc-eqnos-script.py", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xed' in file C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\pandoc-eqnos-script.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
Error running filter pandoc-eqnos:
Filter returned error status 1`

Installed pandoc-eqnos filter using pip. I sincerely don't know what is causing this error. Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your error message seems to suggest that you should declare the encoding. Did you read the documentation that the error links to?

Comment: I'm such a fool.. I completely miss that. The error was solved. Thanks, @Azer.

Comment: No problem, glad it worked :)

Comment: If there is a problem with how pandoc-eqnos installed with pip, then please report an Issue so it can be addressed for all users: https://github.com/tomduck/pandoc-eqnos/issues